# Firing event on product duplication

Tags: magento, events, magento-1.7, product

What I want to do is to empty the custom 'EAN' field of a product that gets copied in the backend. So as soon as the user hits 'copy' on an item the new items EAN field should be empty.

I found the magento event 'product_duplicate_attributes' but I am not sure if its what I need. Is there any way to fire an event if a product gets duplicated or maybe an even simpler solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

[image: (A): The field that should become empty, (B): Trigger event on save]
*(A): The field that should become empty, (B): Trigger event on save.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem:

*etc/config.xml:*

```
    <models>              
 <ledscom_eanremover>
               <class>LedsCom_EanRemover_Model</class>
                </ledscom_eanremover>
            </models>
        </global>
        <adminhtml>
            <events>
                <catalog_model_product_duplicate><!-- Observe product duplication. -->
                    <observers>
                        <ledscom_eanremover>
                            <class>ledscom_eanremover/observer</class>
                            <method>removeEan</method>
                        </ledscom_eanremover>
                    </observers>
                </catalog_model_product_duplicate>
            </events>
        </adminhtml>
```

*Model/Observer.php*

```
<?php
class LedsCom_EanRemover_Model_Observer{
    public function removeEan($observer){
        $new_product = $observer->getEvent()->getNewProduct();          // Get new product from event-observer.
        $new_product->setData('ean', null);                             // Remove the ean of the new product.                                           
    }
}
```

I am listening to the 'catalog_model_product_duplicate' event and remove the ean of the duplicated product.